# Node.js хранение актуального состояния с доступом для всех пользователей

Tags: node.js, сокет, socket.io, хранение-данных

Пишу проект использующий node.js + socket.io для онлайн игры, ограниченной по времени (1 час) и количеству пользователей (20-30).
Задача - хранить общие данные (объект данных) состояния игры в памяти ноды, на время игры, которые могут быть доступны глобально (чтение/запись) для каждого подключенного пользователя участника игры. Как это реализовать в node.js?

Comment: Лучше не храните в памяти никакие данные, это скорее всего выстрелит в ногу. Не бойтесь организовывать такие штуки в БД.

Comment: redis будет весьма кстати для вашей задачи

Comment: Да эти варианты тоже рассматриваю для использования - хранить все в БД (mysql, mongodb, redis). Но в данном случае интересует механизм хранения данных в ноде по принципу такому как socket.io например хранит список пользователей комнаты, доступный каждому пользователю этой комнаты в глобальной области

Comment: Если хочется хранить именно в памяти то можно сделать глобальный JSON в нём создавать id игры, и уже в объекте id хранить данные

Comment: @vnn198  Да проблема моя была в том что этот json объект определял через var внутри io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) { ... });  и потому он не был виден глобально. Вынес наружу и объект стал видимым глобально.  Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы хранить в памяти ноды данные доступные для каждого пользователя, достаточно создать глобальную переменную (объект) в начала скрипта, и там сохранять данные для текущей игры. Эта переменная будет видна и доступна для редактирования для каждого подключившегося пользователя.
P.S.  Проблема была изначально в том что объект определял через var внутри io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) { ... }); и потому он не был виден глобально

Comment: а как вы добились видимости глобальной переменной в разных процессах (воркерах)? если их пока нет - то рано или поздно у вас появится кластер и эти проблемы